# VIM: How to call a vimscript function after press a shortcut or execute a command?

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript

I want to know how to call a function after a normal or Ex command.

Examples:

- bind a function to search command. When I input `/xxxx` to search `xxxx`, also call the function.
- press `*` to highlight occurrences, then also execute a function.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I've cleaned up your question with an [edit].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of `*` (or similar normal mode commands) you just remap it:

```
func! MyFunc()
    echom "Hello World"
endfunc

nnoremap * *:call MyFunc()<CR>
```

For the search `/xxxx` you can redefine `<CR>` mapping in commandline:

```
func! SearchCR()
    if getcmdtype() =~ "[/?]"
        echom "Run Something if CR was pressed in /search"
    endif
endfunc

cnoremap <CR> <cmd>call SearchCR()<CR><CR>
```

This would work only in recent vim (with support of a new `<cmd>`)

PS, there are no "hooks" in vim to attach to selected normal mode commands, although there are autocommands that could be used to run your code on some events.